# Date range picker in non-military format

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I am working on a project that requires the daterange picker to be in non-military format, while still enforcing a min date. The current set up works although the daterange picker is in military format, despite setting `timePicker24Hour: false,` - I need the picker to be in non-military format. Any idea why this is and how to accomplish this?

```
$('input[name="launchdate"]').daterangepicker({
                                    timePicker24Hour: false,
                                    timePickerIncrement: 15,
                                    singleDatePicker: true,
                                    showDropdowns: true,
                                    timePicker: true,
                                    autoApply: true,
                                    minDate: moment().hour(13).minutes(0),
                                    format: 'hh:mm A',
                                    locale: {
                                        format: "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"
                                    }
                                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine!

Here is a short snippet which gives you **non-military time format** with  (12h) am/pm.

```js
var minDateValue = moment().add(13, 'hours');
$('input[name="launchdate"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker24Hour: false,
    timePickerIncrement: 15,
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    timePicker: true,
    autoApply: true,
    minDate: minDateValue,
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    locale: {
        format: "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />


<!-- Input -->
<input name="launchdate"/>
```

If you want to **get military time format** (24h):

Remove the `A` in your `format` options and set `timePicker24Hour` to `true`.

**EDIT:** added `moment().add(13, 'hours')` as `minDate` value.

Comment: I guess you need some kind of preprocessing your min-date, will soon update the answer

Comment: @AnchovyLegend See my updated code snippet. Thanks for the vote!